# Eclipse buildship gradle configuration (gradlew, or --init-script)

Tags: eclipse, gradle, buildship

My company uses a customized `gradlew` that passes `--init-script` and `--project-prop` options to gradle.

```
#!/bin/bash
exec gradle \
  --init-script "$company/init.d/init.gradle.kts" \
  -PcompanyGradleRepo=$companyGradleRepo \
  "$@"
```

How can I pass the these same options to eclipse buildship, which I run via eclipse.jdt.ls

Comment: In Eclipse, there is a "program arguments" box in the "new gradle project" window, in the gradle import wizard

Comment: or, you could add a "dev" profile to the build. The dev profile would be active on a development box (eg. when some files are detected under user-home), and would enable DEV settings (whatever is set by the custom init.gradle script)

Comment: I don't run eclipse, I run the eclipse.jdt.ls which has no UI. There is a file `.settings/org.eclipse.buildship.core.prefs` which has a `arguments` value. Maybe I can set my options there. I'm also noticing a `connection.gradle.distribution`, maybe I can set that to `./gradlew`.